# how to isolate kubernetes namespaces but allow access from outside

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster setup using kubeadm
I'm trying to define a network policy which restricts access from outside the namespace but doesn't block access from outside (external IP)
to elaborate I want the pods to be accessible from other pods in the namespace and via external IP address but not from other namespaces
any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into OpenShift? It is a Kubernetes fork with better multitenant support, and does this out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following network policy and it worked for me

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: policy-test
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access: "true"
```

based on what I know the external access is granted through kube-proxy which is a pod in kube-system namespace. this network policy will allow all the pods from policy-test namespace and any namespace with access=true label
applying this network policy and adding the access=true label to kube-system namespace will solve the issue

**adding the label :**

```
kubectl label namespace/kube-system access=true
```

Comment: This is tricky, I wish there was a cleaner solution