# AKS Isolate Service in namespace

Tags: networking, kubernetes, aks

We deploy a service to our existing AKS cluster that needs to be isolated as much as possible so it can't access other services or resources in our cluster.

I created a new kubernetes namespace and deployed the service there.
Next i would like to lock down the network in this namespace so the service can be reached from the outside world via HTTPS but can not access other services running in the same AKS cluster (but in different namespaces).

For that, i deployed a Network Policy, denying all egress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace: namespace-where-service-is-deployed
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

based on: https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/security/kubernetes-network-policy

This works but it totally blocks all egress. I need the service to be able to access it's database (CosmosDB) which is running outside the AKS cluster.
Also i would like log transmission via Application Insights to work.

Is there a way to isolate the service without having to figure out all the IP Adresses of CosmosDB and App Insights and allowing them explicitly?

We are running on Kubernetes Version 1.23.8 and using the Network Plugin "kubenet" with the Network Policy "calico".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to achieve the isolation by restricting ingress to the namespace where my other workload was deployed (which should not be accessed from the service to isolate) based on this approach:
[how to isolate kubernetes namespaces but allow access from outside](https://serverfault.com/questions/933230/how-to-isolate-kubernetes-namespaces-but-allow-access-from-outside)

But as "the outside" in my case was the Ingress Controller, i applied the label to the Namespace where the Ingress Controller was deployed instead of kube-system.